OpenGL: Qt3D.Renderer.OpenGL.Backend: Unable to find suitable Texture Unit for "diffuseTexture" solution
I am using QT 5.15.10 to render a 3d model (Collada dae file format)
When I try to load the file, the above OpenGL: Qt3D.Renderer.OpenGL.Backend: Unable to find suitable Texture Unit for "diffuseTexture" endlessly prompts.
[https://bitbucket.org/amahta/3d_viewer/src/master/main.qml] This is the sample qml code that I took reference. I did some research but I am not sure if I have to explicitly set the texture unit. I saw many information on how to do this on the cpp backend side, but there seems to be no information doing this on the qml. Or could it be that I missed some stuff while exporting the model from blender?? I am really lost and any help will be really appreciated!

Without additional code to review, I can only guess that you are using a Qt3D material that expects a texture (.jpg, .png) and that texture hasn't been initialized correctly:

the image file doesn't exist;
or the path to that image file is wrong.

